# How to I call a variable somewhere else in my code in VB?

Tags: vb.net

So, I have the following VB code:

```
Try
        Using verSR As New StreamReader(appDataVersionLoc)
            Dim txtVern As String
            txtVern = verSR.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim verFile As System.IO.FileStream
        verFile = System.IO.File.Create(appDataVersionLoc)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("appDataVersionLoc", "0.0.0.0", True)
        MessageBox.Show("Version file missing/corrupt, created a new one.")
    End Try
```

See that variable called "txtVern?" I'm trying to use that somewhere else in my code outside of the Try-End Try block.
Pretty much this:

```
Try
        Using verSR As New StreamReader(appDataVersionLoc)
            Dim txtVern As String
            txtVern = verSR.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim verFile As System.IO.FileStream
        verFile = System.IO.File.Create(appDataVersionLoc)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("appDataVersionLoc", "0.0.0.0", True)
        MessageBox.Show("Version file missing/corrupt, created a new one.")
    End Try

    blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

    Dim currentversion As String = txtVern
```

Now, I'm a complete VB noob, and I'm getting this error:

> 'txtVern' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
>   protection level.

How can I fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable declared inside any block is visible only inside that block. You have to move declaration before `Try` block:

```
Dim txtVern As String = String.Empty
Try
    Using verSR As New StreamReader(appDataVersionLoc)
        txtVern = verSR.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    Dim verFile As System.IO.FileStream
    verFile = System.IO.File.Create(appDataVersionLoc)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("appDataVersionLoc", "0.0.0.0", True)
    MessageBox.Show("Version file missing/corrupt, created a new one.")
End Try

blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

Dim currentversion As String = txtVern
```

Answer (score 0):

In declaring your variable txtVern in your try block you are limiting their scope to the try block. Try declaring them at the beginning of your subroutine.